# How to differenciate mousemove inputs of multiple mouse devices?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, pinvoke

I have a mouse and a touchpad on my laptop. I want a global hook for mousemove that tells me not only the new position, but also the physical device where it came from. Subscribing the hook only to the touchpad would be an even better solution, since I'm only interested in the touchpad. The hook has to work system wide (even if my application is not in focus).

How can I do this?

I'm not afraid to use Pinvoke in my C#/WPF application

Answer (score 1):

You could use
[P-Invoke user32.getrawinputdeviceinfo](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getrawinputdeviceinfo) . 
For mouse input you can get thing such:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct RID_DEVICE_INFO_MOUSE
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    public int dwId;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    public int dwNumberOfButtons;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    public int dwSampleRate;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    public int fHasHorizontalWheel;
}
```

and, about Device:

```
StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct RID_DEVICE_INFO_HID
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    public int dwVendorId;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    public int dwProductId;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    public int dwVersionNumber;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
    public ushort usUsagePage;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
    public ushort usUsage;
}
```